# How can I add a handler to track and set the active tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightningnavigation

Due to the fact that I need to get two **badges**, I decided to modify the standard `lightning-vertical-navigation` (in which there can only be one). But now I don't understand how I can switch the active tab? The standard version has `onselect`, which no longer works here. I have little experience in this, so I would really appreciate your help!

```
<nav class="slds-nav-vertical" aria-label="Sub page">
    <div class="slds-nav-vertical__section">
        <h2 id="entity-header" class="slds-nav-vertical__title">Months</h2>
        <div for:each={listMonth} for:item="month" key={month.Id}>
            <ul aria-describedby="entity-header">
            <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active">
                <a href="#" class="slds-nav-vertical__action" aria-current="false">{month.nameMonth}
                <span class="slds-badge slds-col_bump-left">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">:</span>{month.countAmount}
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">New Items</span>
                </span>
                <span class="slds-badge slds-col_bump-left">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">:</span>{month.countIncome}
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">New Items</span>
                </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: kudos on building the markup for the component =)

Answer (score 0):

the vertical nav blueprints have class names which you can use and toggle based on the selected tab:

```
...<li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active">...
```

as you can see, `slds-is-active` indicates what tab is active, and modifies the css in consequence, so, when you click on a `slds-nav-vertical__item` you can toggle it.

You will need to add an onclick handler and a propery to identify what tab is ebing clicked so you can toggle the class.

At the same time, you will want to remove the active property/class name from all other elements when you change tabs.

you can achieve this using a template.querySelectorAll on the `slds-nav-vertical__item` and remove the active class name, before toggling the `active` class name on the selected tab.